# How to show and hide two routes with infobubbles and markers in HERE MAP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, here-api

I am working on one requirement where I have to show two routes in the map based for comparison, User will be given an HTML page with two checkbox for each route. Based on the checkbox selection respective route will be added and removed from the map.

I am using `group.removeAll()` and `map.removeObject(polyline)`. for single route it is working fine but When I am trying out with two routes,

looks like `removeObject` and `removeAll` API is not removing all objects together, it is only removing a certain one. I tried with `map.removeObjects(map.getObject())`, still no luck. Can someone please explain using these APIs.

thank you.

It is giving me below error :

> "H.map.Group#removeObject object not found"

I am using the same API given in HERE developers demo code and rendering it.

Comment: Any help on this please ? Do we have any official technical support for HERE MAP APIs, since I see in their website they have mentioned to ask questions here to get support.

Comment: Please share your request code and the response for us to help you better.